# Click event not being captured for ListView items with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have a `ListView` with multiple elements for each row as follows:

**list_element.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/global_container"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">
```

`Fragment1.java` is inflating the layout that contains the listview which has the elements above.

I need to be able to capture click events for each item to change the color of an element when the item is clicked and when another item is clicked restore it to its original color as the new item  changes the element color and so on.

**This means that I tried to capture `OnItemClickListener` inside `Fragment1.java`:**

```
    if (rootView != null) {
        myList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    }

    ArrayList l = new ArrayList();

//Bogus list
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        l.add(new Object());
    }

    adapter = new MyListAdapter(l, getActivity());

    myList.setAdapter(adapter);


    final MyListAdapter ad = adapter;

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            ad.setClickedPosition(position);
    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

But (I assume) all the Touch events of `HorizontalScrollView` are capturing the click/touch... event and I get no response. As you can see I tried `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and changing focusability back and forth with no results.

**I also tried capturing different events inside the list adapter:**

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element, null, true);

vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.d("aaa", "aaa");


    }
});
```

**And/OR**

```
horizontalScroll = vi.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

horizontalScroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.d("aaa", "aaa");


    }
});
```

Both options without any results. How shall I then capture a click event for an item on the list and keeping to be able to work with the `HorizontalScrollView` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem as follows:

To be able to click on a list item this two things needed to be done.

- First:

  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

needs to be present on the top-most element of the row element layout.

- Second:

  android:clickable="false"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

these 3 properties need to be present on the HorizontalScrollView.

The problem with that solution is that HorizontalScrollView won't work per se, so you need to activate it once the click event is detected. I do it on the getView() method of the adapter.

When the element is clicked I pass the position to the adapter:

**fragment.java**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {

        //Private method inside the adapter
        ad.setClickedPosition(position);
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

**adapter.java**

```
public void setClickedPosition(int clickedPosition) {
    this.clickedPosition = clickedPosition;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (clickedPosition == position)
        holder.scrollview.setScrollingEnabled(true);
    else
        holder.scrollview.setScrollingEnabled(false);  
 }
```

**CustomHorizontalScrollview.java**

```
    public void setScrollingEnabled (boolean enabled) {
        this.isScrollEnabled = enabled;
    }

//...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    //...

    if (isScrollEnabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    //...
}
```

Something to be considered is that this solution works for me since the behaviour "first click then swipe" is what I was looking for, so be aware this might not be exactly what you want but should help you in your quest to make that work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! For my case it was already sufficient to set android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
in the parents.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your list_element.xml as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/global_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't work, this is how it originally was.